# Probability of events under homeomorphism

Tags: probability

This is just a question I thought of.

> Suppose we have $2$ topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and there exists a homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$. Suppose $A$ is an event in $X$ (throwing a dice maybe), having probabilty $P(A)$. If the corresponding event $A'$ occurs in the space $Y$ and the probability is $P(A')$, can we predict the value for $P(A')$ from the knowledge of $P(A)$ and the homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$?

Comment: What does it mean to speak of an event in a topological space?

Comment: You might have to *define* the probability on $Y$ to be $P_Y(S)\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=}P_X(f^{-1}(S))$

Comment: @lulu: I suppose OP means a space that has both a probability structure and a topological structure

Comment: Suppose i consider the drunkards walk on a 2d plane that is the space $R^2$ and define the event as the person reaching a point (x,y) . Now i consider the sphere ($R^3$) for the drunkards walk nd define A' to be the event of him reaching a point ($r,\theta,\phi$).

Comment: Yes, MPW, i have assumed that the space has a defined probability structure.

Comment: @MPW  Well, maybe.  But as you point out being homeomorphic topologically has nothing to do with any measure theoretic considerations.

Comment: @Lelouch  But what's the relation between the probabilistic structures?  Suppose, say $X=[0,1]=Y$ and $f$ is the identity.  But we give $X$ the uniform distribution and $Y$ something else.  Then knowing $P(A)$ is clearly insufficient.

Comment: This is one example where it is insufficient. Is it so always for any2 such spaces? Or are there cases, where we can exploit their relation to find the probability?

Comment: In most well-behaved probability spaces removing a point produces no effect. In most well-behaved topological spaces removing a point introduces drastic changes to the homeomorphism class. So, I think you need to specify a lot of structures on the things you are talking about.